# spring batch stop a job after 10 seconds

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to run a job in the background, allowing me to stop it by some condition or after a timeout has occurred.

I have these two chunks of code:

One:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={EmbeddedISpringBatchConfiguration.class, MonitoredJobConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RunMonitoredJob2 {

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

@Autowired
private Job job;

@Test
public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception {

    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    execution.stop();
}
```

Two:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={EmbeddedISpringBatchConfiguration.class, MonitoredJobConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RunMonitoredJob {

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

@Autowired
private Job job;

@Test
public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception {

    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher().run(job, new JobParameters());

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    execution.stop();
}

public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

In option one, The job first finishes and only then goes to the "sleep"

In option tow, the job does not run the steps in my job.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you try by increasing sleep time in approach # 2 ? ( Just to verify that time was not short enough that nothing could be executed ). Approach # 1 will not work as that is a synchronous execution and caller waits till run is completed.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer.
You should define the JobLauncher as async using:


@Bean
    JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }



Then call it as usual and as a "stop":

  JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

Thread.sleep(5000);

execution.stop();

Comment: Just for the completeness, could you please show `threadPoolTaskExecutor() ` too in your question? Yes, thats the idea that job can be prematurely stopped only if it returns execution immediately and not making main to wait for completion.

Comment: Sure: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try using scheduler, which will invoke after specific time interval, instead of Thread.sleep

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${cron.batch-timeout-check-delay}", initialDelayString = "${cron.batch-timeout-check-initial-delay}")
    public void execute() throws Exception{
      //get jobExceutionId of job to stop
      JobExceution jobExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExceution(jobExceutionId);
      boolean isTimeout = (new Date().getTime() - jobExecution.getCreateTime().getTime()) > 50000 //Here timout
      if(isTimeout){
        jobexceution.stop();
      }
    }
```